# Can´t upload data via SFTP

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, file-server

I tried to upload a folder on my Raspberry Pi using Cyberduck SFTP, this has ALWAYS worked for me, but now it doesn´t I have no idea why. Thank you in advance.
[image: Cyberduck]

Comment: what folder are you trying to upload to (full path) and what user are you using to connect?

Comment: /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/world via SFTP to /home/pi/minecraft and the user is the standart user (pi)

Comment: I used this method many times and it worked, but now it is something wrong with the read/write rights

Comment: I also tried different network filemanagers (Cyberduck and ForkLift)

Comment: file:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/world -> sftp://192.168.0.218/home/pi/minecraft

Comment: No need to use graphical tool, command line will serve you quicker: "scp -r /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/world pi@ip_to_Pi:/home/pi/minecraft"

Answer (score 2):

What is the output of executing this (on the Pi)?

```
ls -l /home/pi/minecraft
```

If the folder is, e.g., owned root and not world writable, regular users cannot place anything there.

Comment: -bash: s: command not found

Comment: I think you missed the 'l' in 'ls'

Comment: ok, now the output is: total 0

Comment: Ok! Sorry, do: 'ls -l /home/pi | grep minecraft' without the quotes obviously!

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  4 10:41 minecraft

Comment: it is something wrong with the folder, now I can move the folder into /home/pi/ but when I try to move it into /home/pi/minecraft it says: Permission denied (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED: The user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.).

Comment: The minecraft folder is owned by root, which means regular users can't do anything to it. Execute "sudo chown pi:pi ~/minecraft" to fix.